# Prevent aldeed/meteor-tabular from showing counts at the bottom of tables

Tags: mongodb, meteor, datatables

I am having issues with a slow Meteor app. I have narrowed it down to mongo performance, and am using the profiler to look at slow queries. I have a bunch of queries taking over 10 seconds. They all look approximately like the output below.

I believe these queries are coming from the row count at the bottom of each datatable in [meteor-tabular](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular). The table may have tens of thousands of rows, but each page should only show tens or hundreds of rows. I don't realy need the `count` and would be happy to kill it if it is indeed causing these performance issues.

I found no way to disable this page count in meteor-datatables or in datatables itself. Is there a way?

```
{
  "op" : "command",
  "command" : {
    "count" : "myCollection",
    "query" : {
      "user_id" : "someId"
    },
    "fields" : null
  },
  "keyUpdates" : 0,
  "writeConflicts" : 0,
  "numYield" : 1180,
  "locks" : {
    "Global" : {
      "acquireCount" : {
        "r" : NumberLong(2362)
      }
    },
    "MMAPV1Journal" : {
      "acquireCount" : {
        "r" : NumberLong(2345)
      },
      "acquireWaitCount" : {
        "r" : NumberLong(3)
      },
      "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
        "r" : NumberLong(26215)
      }
    },
    "Database" : {
      "acquireCount" : {
        "r" : NumberLong(1181)
      }
    },
    "Collection" : {
      "acquireCount" : {
        "R" : NumberLong(1181)
      },
      "acquireWaitCount" : {
        "R" : NumberLong(1164)
      },
      "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
        "R" : NumberLong(12358760)
      }
    }
  },
  "responseLength" : 44,
  "millis" : 33332,
  "execStats" : {

  },
  "client" : "XX.XXX.XX.XXX"
}
```

Comment: Not sure if you're on the right track. You could fork the [package](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular) and remove the computation to see if that helps. There's only one `.count()` on the server and one on the client. https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=.count%28

Comment: You could hide with jquery `$('#example').dataTable({
       "bInfo" : false
   });`

Comment: @MichelFloyd I will try that

Comment: @Gandalf that won't help, the calculation will still be performed.

Comment: @maxko87 I also faced this issue and boy was it bogging things down. I had to move from galaxy to heroku to aws but i finally moved from datatables to reactive table and the speed of my apps improved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is having this issue, I fixed it in my fork:

https://github.com/maxko87/meteor-tabular

I also submitted a pull request to aldeed/meteor-tabular, we'll see if that gets pulled in.